# Broken WooCommerce submenu links in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I was messing around in my WordPress site with WooCommerce plugin. Suddenly all Woo sub-menu links in admin (Orders, Customers, Settings etc.) are broken. In path, my site name is replaced with `woocommerce`. For example: this - `http://example.com/?page=wc-settings/` turns into -> `woocommerce/?page=wc-settings`. How can I fix this? Only link that are working are `Orders`.

Things I tried:

- Save permalinks
- Disable all plugins -> Save permalinks
- Change theme -> Save permalinks
- Tried to override all sub-menu. Filter hook just returned Order link. So nothing to override
- Cleared cache -> Save permalinks

Note: I am developing some plugin in that site but it does not brake the links. I activated my plugin in brand new WP site with Woo and links did not broke. Maybe there is something that I did before and it overrode links permanently, but I cant recall what that would be. Maybe someone knows how to change them. I'm open to monkey patches too.

Comment: What is that plugin doing? Check your logs or if you don't remember what you did, just load a previous backup.

Comment: Logs say nothing and I don't have backups. Plugins syncs products with other management tool. Does not alter any menus or woocommerce filters.

Comment: In woocommerce general settings, there are two fields, called "WordPress Address (URL)" and other called "Site Address (URL)". What those say?

Comment: These fields are in WordPress General settings and they are fine, my sites full url. If those were not fine, my site won't work, but messed up are only Woo sub-menu links.